# how to call one service from another service using azure service bus relay

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebusrelay

We are using WCF services with Azure service bus.

I referred this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-hybrid-app-using-service-bus-relay/

I have following scenarios:

1. I have created Service1 which is directly consumed by client (Within the same namespace with path servicePath1).
   For example: sb://MyNamespace.servicebus.windows.net/servicePath1
2. I have created Service2 which is directly consumed by client (Within the same namespace with path servicePath2).
   For example: sb://MyNamespace.servicebus.windows.net/servicePath2

Service1 and Service2 are also together consumed by client.

> I had to consume Service2 within Service1 or vice versa (as per business need)and I achieved this by considering Service1 as client for Service2.

It is working fine but I wanted to know better way to achieve this.

Please guide or share pointers.

Comment: If you can consume Service1 from a client, why wouldn't you be able to consume Service1 from Service2?

Comment: @TheDude: Now I am able to consume Service1 from Service2 and vice versa, I want other standard way to do this task. I am first time implementing Service Oriented Architecture using Azure Service Bus.

Comment: You can always create a non-relay WCF endpoint that a service can consume. If you have only relay endpoints, you can only consume them by going through Azure.